# Echo $_POST with $.ajax in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

I'm trying to `echo $_POST` with `$.ajax` in PHP with no success. In Xdebug I see the `$_POST` get the right value and executing the `echo $_POST` line, but I keep getting the `else` output clause. Also in chrome I see the headers that are sent valid. All the code is in the same page index.php.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.post demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="but">Click Me!</button>

<script>
    $('#but').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: {name: "John"},
            success: function() {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    echo $_POST['name'];
} else {
    echo "Nothing to Show";
}
?>
```

Comment: is index.php and HTML script on the same file?

Comment: @Pupil Yes, In the same page.

Comment: Put the PHP code in it's own page.

Comment: @wizard When you call index.php in ajax it will return you all the HTML code at the top. Better put php into a separate file and call it.

Comment: To add to the above comments, you are not doing anything with the output of the php script in your ajax call so you will only see your `success` alert. And when you reload the page, it will be a GET request again. If you display the returned value in your `succes` function, you will see the complete html source of your pagge with the text `John` at the end.

Comment: @user4035 But I need it in the same page. Anyway, I care less about the return, I most care about the request.

Comment: @wizard Obviously you care about the return value, otherwise there would be no reason to `echo` anything.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the whole page is being returned in response to your AJAX request; HTML and all. You're also not retrieving the value returned from the request in your JS code, to do that you just need to accept a parameter on your `success` handler. Try this:

In it's own file, say `foo.php`:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        echo $_POST['name'];
    } else {
        echo "Nothing to Show";
    }
?>
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<script>
    $('#but').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'text', // to ensure jQuery doesn't try to deserialise the repsonse
            url: "foo.php",
            data: { name: "John" },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response.trim()); // = 'John'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Still Not good. I would like to mention that I care less about the response right now. I just want to be able to echo the $_POST request.

Comment: But that makes no sense - to see the echoed PHP variable you ***have*** to get the response from the AJAX request. This should be working though - check the console for errors.

Comment: I understand you, but again I want to echo the result using PHP. Likewise, echo $_POST result from a form submit (It's works out of the box).

Comment: You seem confused about how AJAX works. You are echoing the result via PHP, which is then read by the JS which fired off the request.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax will return a response and you can use that response to display. It will not work on the same page.

Try as below :

main.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.post demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="but">Click Me!</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    $('#but').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: {name: "John"},
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    echo $_POST['name'];
} else {
    echo "Nothing to Show";
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, But I want to echo the $_POST using PHP.